# Openstack instance shutdowns

Tags: openstack

I am running openstack yoga on centos stream8 and trying to upgrade to Centos Stream9. After upgrading the OS to stream9 I have updated all the containers from the Kolla project, once after the nova-libvirt container update the VMS on all computes went shutoff.

The VM logs says the VM is crashed,

```
###############
2023-11-02T10:35:17.176841Z qemu-kvm: terminating on signal 15 from pid 1 (/usr/lib/systemd/systemd)
2023-11-02 10:35:18.237+0000: shutting down, reason=crashed
##################
```

libvirtd log says:

```
#################
2023-11-02 10:35:15.390+0000: 943900: error : virNetSocketReadWire:1792 : End of file while reading data: Input/output error
2023-11-02 10:35:18.237+0000: 48132: info : libvirt version: 8.0.0, package: 22.module_el8+596+27e96798 (builder@centos.org, 2023-07-31-14:36:36, )
2023-11-02 10:35:18.237+0000: 48132: error : qemuMonitorOpenUnix:234 : failed to connect to monitor socket: No such file or directory
2023-11-02 10:35:18.237+0000: 48133: error : qemuMonitorOpenUnix:234 : failed to connect to monitor socket: No such file or directory
2023-11-02 10:35:18.252+0000: 47937: error : virNetDevSendEthtoolIoctl:2937 : ethtool ioctl error on tapdff0f159-61: No such device
2023-11-02 10:35:18.256+0000: 47937: error : virNetDevSendEthtoolIoctl:2937 : ethtool ioctl error on tapdff0f159-61: No such device
2023-11-02 10:35:18.259+0000: 47937: error : virNetDevSendEthtoolIoctl:2937 : ethtool ioctl error on tapdff0f159-61: No such device
2023-11-02 10:35:18.262+0000: 47937: error : virNetDevSendEthtoolIoctl:2937 : ethtool ioctl error on tapdff0f159-61: No such device
2023-11-02 10:35:18.265+0000: 47937: error : virNetDevSendEthtoolIoctl:2937 : ethtool ioctl error on tapdff0f159-61: No such device
2023-11-02 10:35:18.269+0000: 47937: error : virNetDevSendEthtoolIoctl:2937 : ethtool ioctl error on tapdff0f159-61: No such device
2023-11-02 10:35:18.272+0000: 47937: error : virNetDevSendEthtoolIoctl:2937 : ethtool ioctl error on tapdff0f159-61: No such device
2023-11-02 10:35:18.275+0000: 47937: error : virNetDevSendEthtoolIoctl:2937 : ethtool ioctl error on tapdff0f159-61: No such device

#######################################
```

let me know if you have some inputs on this.